# pptp vpn - Kill User Connection

Tags: vpn, connection, pptp, kill

I'd like to be able to terminate a user's connection to my pptp server from the server itself without interrupting anyone else's connection. Problem is - I have no idea how and have found no useful information via the usual channels (google, basically).

Any help is much appreciated!

**Edit** I'm using Debian.

Comment: What type of PPTP server are you running?

Comment: The standard pptp package on Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that Debian uses the PoPToP `pptpd`, which in turn uses `pppd`. The `pptpd` process forks for each new user connection so you should just be able to `kill` the 'pppd' process related to the user you want to terminate.

The process list doesn't show the username associated with the `pppd` process for a given connection, so you'll probably have to use the `last` command to figure out what IP address user the user logged-on from and then kill the appropriate `pppd` process. `pptpd`, by default, updates the `wtmp` file with logons, so `last` should show you from what ip address a user logged-on from. Then it's a matter of grepping the process list for that `pppd` instance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a Windows PPTP server we're talking about, you can go to Administrative Tools->Routing and Remote access and then select "Remote Access Clients" on the left. From there, you can disconnect them.

Comment: Ah no, I'm using Debian Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu as PPTP-VPN Server.

1. `last | grep ppp | head`    to show current connected clients.
2. `ps aux|grep pptpd`       to show connected clients's pid and assigned ip.
3. `killall pppd`    to kill all client's connection
4. `kill $pid`       to kill specific client and disconnect it.