# Can radius interact with pptp beyond authentication?

Tags: pptp, freeradius

I've managed to setup pptp to use Radius authentication - making it much easier to manage users in an sql database than the default password file. However, ideally I'd like to be able to get the status of these users and disconnect/manage them as Radius allows - is this possible? If so, could you elaborate and point me in the right direction?

All help is much appreciated!

**Edit** I am personally using Debian and the standard aptitude packages for pptp and FreeRADIUS.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered OpenVPN ? I found that was far better documented, although you may run into more difficulties if you are using the Windows VPN client.

Comment: I'd like to stick with pptp, ideally.

Answer (score 0):

I'll second @Niewee's OpenVPN recommendation just because it's easier to monitor and manage active connections, especially if you opt for something like [OpenVPN-AS server](http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/overview.html), the (cheap) supported option.  Also note that it can use Radius for authentication as well.  The OpenVPN client for Windows works fine.

However, if you want to use PPTP [here is a Serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/195409/pptp-vpn-kill-user-connection) that covers disconnecting user connections on pptpd/debian well.  If you're using a sql backend for FreeRadius you should be able to query the auth tables directly to get status information.