# How to disconnect pptp client?

Tags: centos6, pptp, pptpd, pptp-client

How to disconnect pptp client connected to Cent OS 6.2 server from the server side ?
ifdown ppp0 doesn't work.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate question [http://serverfault.com/questions/195409/pptp-vpn-kill-user-connection](http://serverfault.com/questions/195409/pptp-vpn-kill-user-connection). The question has also already been answered so please refer to that.

Answer (score 0):

simply try any of following. That should work. 
here #pid is process id of pptp service.

```
`kill $pid` or `killall pppd`
```

or use

```
# kill {pppd-PID}
```

Comment: use 'sudo' if you have permission issues, needless to say :)

Comment: I want to disconnect particular client. but killing process will disconnect all the client.

Comment: try to find process id of the client you want to disconnect my be "ps aux" will give you in detail and you can see which one you want to disconnect. and then with kill #pid you can kill it.

Comment: correction: "# kill {pppd-PID}"

Comment: one process handles all client connection. Can you suggest me solution without stopping service or without killing process?

Comment: I am afraid if I can tell you something like that. Wait for somebody else here :) Sorry mate!

Answer (score 0):

You can use accel-ppp, because it has a really powerful cli. And you can disconnect particular user without any problem.

```
# telnet 127.0.0.1 2000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
accel-ppp version c0b2b260b2c9b8c3375d51e90cd1edf552d7655a
Password: ******
```

The ip address 127.0.0.1 and port 2000 has been configured through main config file accel-ppp.conf

```
[cli]
telnet=127.0.0.1:2000
tcp=127.0.0.1:2001
password=1234567
```

To get current sessions you can use '***show sessions***' command

```
accel-ppp# show sessions
 ifname | username |  calling-sid  |       ip       | type | comp | state  |  uptime
--------+----------+---------------+----------------+------+------+--------+----------
 ppp0   | alex     | 192.168.1.7   | 192.168.216.10 | pptp | mppe | active | 00:32:50
 ppp1   | john     | 192.168.1.100 | 192.168.216.11 | l2tp | mppe | active | 00:00:49
```

To terminate specific one you can use '***terminate***' command

```
accel-ppp# terminate username john soft

accel-ppp# show sessions
 ifname | username | calling-sid |       ip       | type | comp | state  |  uptime
--------+----------+-------------+----------------+------+------+--------+----------
 ppp0   | alex     | 192.168.1.7 | 192.168.216.10 | pptp | mppe | active | 00:34:57
```

Terminate command has a lot of options

```
terminate if <interface> [soft|hard]- terminate session by interface name
        [match] username <username> [soft|hard]- terminate session by username
        ip <addresss> [soft|hard]- terminate session by ip address
        csid <id> [soft|hard]- terminate session by calling station id
        sid <id> [soft|hard]- terminate session by session id
        all [soft|hard]- terminate all sessions
```

In a log file /var/log/messages you will see

```
Mar 19 13:10:00 vpn accel-pppd: l2tp: new tunnel 59521-1 created following reception of SCCRQ from 192.168.1.100:1701
Mar 19 13:10:00 vpn accel-pppd: l2tp tunnel 59521-1 (192.168.1.100:1701): established at 192.168.1.6:1701
Mar 19 13:10:00 vpn accel-pppd: l2tp tunnel 59521-1 (192.168.1.100:1701): new session 898-1 created following reception of ICRQ
Mar 19 13:10:03 vpn accel-pppd: ppp1:john: connect: ppp1 <--> l2tp(192.168.1.100:1701 session 59521-1, 898-1)
Mar 19 13:10:03 vpn accel-pppd: ppp1:john: john: authentication succeeded
Mar 19 13:10:03 vpn accel-pppd: ppp1:john: IPV6CP: discarding packet
Mar 19 13:10:03 vpn accel-pppd: ppp1:john: session started over l2tp session 59521-1, 898-1
Mar 19 13:12:39 vpn accel-pppd: l2tp session 59521-1, 898-1: data channel closed, disconnecting session
Mar 19 13:12:39 vpn accel-pppd: l2tp tunnel 59521-1 (192.168.1.100:1701): no more session, disconnecting tunnel
```